# Response is not come in a right way in jquery load method

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I uses j query Load Method to load a data in asp.net grid view ,
My Code  for that is

```
  $("#SelectedTestPart").load("PackageForm2.aspx?category=" + currentId2 + " #<%= grdAllSelectedTest1.ClientID %>", function (response) {
     rows = $("tr:gt(0)",response);
      rows.children("td:nth-child(7)").each(function() { ages += parseInt($(this).html()) } );
```

But in the respone Whole html page(including script,both body and head section completely) is come back,i want that only a Html table will be came.
How i Can do this

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in the url before the hash tag. You should delete that.

```
 + " #<%= grdAllSelectedTest1.ClientID %>"
    ^
    |______SPACE
```

Comment: GET http://localhost:50525/MLat17_1_2012/PackageForm2.aspx?category=21_edit
 
GET http://localhost:50525/MLat17_1_2012/Script/aopup.js?_=1327738635144                                           
 
GET http://localhost:50525/MLat17_1_2012/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js?_=1327738635211
 
GET http://localhost:50525/MLat17_1_2012/WebResource...DDuehdzrng2&t=633802855995006876&_=1327738635308
GET http://localhost:50525/MLat17_1_2012/WebResource...8mEmn-FduA2&t=633802855995006876_=1327738635332                                    Now i Get This 5 url when i see by firebug,what is the meaning of that